# jwplayer just downloaded, setup followed, does not appear

Tags: php, javascript, jwplayer

I got great advice from folks on Stackoverflow to use the jwplayer on my site to playback uploaded short videos.
I downloaded the player, followed their setup instructions, nothing.

Here is their simple 2-step process, and I followed it:

**STEP #1 Upload Player Files to Website**

Transfer the player.swf, jwplayer.js and swfobject.js file from the ZIP to your website. We recommend putting these files in a folder named "jwplayer" in the root of your site. Make sure that you've also uploaded all the necessary videos, songs and/or images to your site."

**STEP #2 Embed Player Code into HTML**

Embed the player in your HTML page with the lines of code below. Note: If you place the files in different directories, make sure to set the references in this code accordingly.

The jwplayer site provided the javascript code to use:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='mediaplayer'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
   'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
   'id': 'playerID',
   'width': '480',
   'height': '270',
   'file': '/videos/video.mp4'
  });
</script>
```

What did they leave out in the above instructions?  I put this exact code
provided on their website at the end of my index.php file, outside of the
php delimiters.  I can't see where I'm doing anything wrong.
I created the two folders 'videos' and 'jwplayer' under my website's folder
then put the files they specified above inside these folders.
I'm thinking there's more install steps they left out because the player
does not even appear, just a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the path of SWF in the code:

```
...
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
 'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
...
```

Comment: It was in fact a path problem.  The setup instructions were wrong.  They say "Transfer the player.swf, jwplayer.js and swfobject.js file from the ZIP to your website. We recommend putting these files in a folder named "jwplayer" in the root of your site."  Well I did make a 'jwplayer' folder in the root of my site.  But that was wrong. After I moved the folder outside of my site's root folder, one folder above my site, now the player shows up. So I'm wondering if my 'localhost' setting is bad? Or something.

Comment: remove the beginning slash(/) from all properties. now u can keep the folder inside your root

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting till the page has loaded with this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='mediaplayer'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEvent(el,t,fn){
  return !!el.attachEventListener?el.attachEventListener(t,fn,false):el.attachEvent("on"+t,fn);
}
```

addEvent(window,"load",function(){
      jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
       'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
       'id': 'playerID',
       'width': '480',
       'height': '270',
       'file': '/videos/video.mp4'
      });
    });

If that still doesn't work then use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) (Firefox) or the Web Inspector (Chrome and Safari) to check if there's a script error, and try to see if you can find and fix the error in the script yourself.

Ad@m

Comment: Sorry that some of the script isn't in monospace font, I can't work out why it is doing that. Ad@m

Comment: Thank you for your effort and your help!